# What materials can be used for Brazing

Tags: materials, welding, brazing

I have trouble understanding the Brazing principle. What I know is that there are a couple of filler materials such as copper, silver, aluminim, etc....

What I remember from the past is that the filler material is different than the material where the two parts I would like to braze are made of (i.e. two stainless steel plates are brazed with copper or titanium filler).

Is it possible to braze two metal parts with the same material for both sides (i.e. is it possible and/or recommended to braze two stainless steel plates with a stainless steel filler?)?

Comment: Soldering, silver soldering, brazing, welding - what are you looking for?

Comment: "i.e. two stainless steel plates are welded with copper" you mean brazed.

Comment: If the parts to be joined melt, then its welding, not brazing.  If they don't melt, then it's brazing (or soldering).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong words. Of course I mean Brazing. Thanks for pointing that out. I am aware of the definition. The question is something else. I got some information that it is possible to use the same materials also for the filling material even though the melting point is the same. This is probably being done for plate type heat exchangers (brazed ones)

Answer (score 1):

Brazing process uses a filler metal with a lower melting temperature so the base metals are not melted ( as in welding). I guess soldering means the filler has a much lower melting temperature.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's a consistent distinction between brazing and soldering, although I'm sure there are a number of strong opinions out there.

Comment: @TimWescott brazing transistors to a pcb?

Comment: @SolarMike OK.  So there's a case that most people will agree with.  I was actually trying to **avoid** pointless etymological discussions by not committing to anything I'm not sure of.

Comment: That is what I also thought of. But the question is finally ... is it possible to use the same filler material as the two pieces I would like to join? You basically said that it is not possible due to the melting temperatures but maybe it is possible with some specific procedures such as vacuum brazing.

Comment: If the filler metal melts at the same temperature as the two pieces that is welding... if the filler melts at a lower temperature it is brazing or soldering...

Comment: Solder is the filler material soldering and brazing is the same process.